# Why is this duplicating the first tables variables?

Tags: java

So basically my issue is that when I open the second SQL database it overwrites my mainInk variables and the secondaryInk variables. It does this in both directions, whether I open main or secondary first.

Heres my system output:
(this is me just opening the first and second SQL databases)

- secondary before main open null
- main before main open null
- main open ID[JZK1027, GRR40084, GRB31001, GRR31002, GRY31833,
  GRG40083, JZW365, JZW466]
- secondary open IDnull
- main before secondary open [JZK1027, GRR40084, GRB31001, GRR31002,
  GRY31833, GRG40083, JZW365, JZW466]
- secondary before secondary open null
- main open ID[535-60430, SF-C8041, SF-M8041, SF-Y8041, 060G36716,
  060Y22870]
- secondary open ID[535-60430, SF-C8041, SF-M8041, SF-Y8041, 060G36716,
  060Y22870]

Code:

```
package main;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.ScrollPane;

public class GUI {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField filenameFieldMain;
private JTextField filenameFieldSecondary;
File fileMain;
File fileSecondary;
String col[] = {"ID", "Name", "Color"};

DefaultTableModel mainModel = new DefaultTableModel(col, 0);
DefaultTableModel secondaryModel = new DefaultTableModel(col, 0);

private JTable main;
private JTable secondary;

static ArrayList<String> mainInkID;
static ArrayList<String> mainInkName;
static ArrayList<String> mainInkColor;
static ArrayList<String> secondaryInkID;
static ArrayList<String> secondaryInkName;
static ArrayList<String> secondaryInkColor;



/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                GUI window = new GUI();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public GUI() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
public void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1200, 900);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    secondary = new JTable(secondaryModel);
    secondary.setBounds(600, 125, 575, 600);
    //frame.getContentPane().add(secondary);

    main = new JTable(mainModel);
    main.setBounds(10, 125, 575, 600);
    //frame.getContentPane().add(main);

    filenameFieldMain = new JTextField();
    filenameFieldMain.setBounds(10, 736, 379, 30);
    frame.getContentPane().add(filenameFieldMain);
    filenameFieldMain.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("SQL Manager");
    lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 11, 1164, 54);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

    filenameFieldSecondary = new JTextField();
    filenameFieldSecondary.setColumns(10);
    filenameFieldSecondary.setBounds(598, 736, 379, 30);
    frame.getContentPane().add(filenameFieldSecondary);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Main");
    lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lblNewLabel_1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(10, 70, 576, 44);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);

    JLabel lblSecondary = new JLabel("Secondary");
    lblSecondary.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblSecondary.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lblSecondary.setBounds(598, 70, 576, 44);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblSecondary);

    ScrollPane scrollPaneMain = new ScrollPane();
    scrollPaneMain.setBounds(10, 125, 575, 600);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPaneMain);
    scrollPaneMain.add(main);

    ScrollPane scrollPaneSecondary = new ScrollPane();
    scrollPaneSecondary.setBounds(600, 125, 575, 600);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPaneSecondary);
    scrollPaneSecondary.add(secondary);


    JButton btnBrowseSecondary = new JButton("Browse");
    btnBrowseSecondary.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
             JFileChooser secondaryFilechoose=new JFileChooser();
                int retval=secondaryFilechoose.showOpenDialog(btnBrowseSecondary);
                if (retval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    //... The user selected a file, get it, use it.
                    fileSecondary = secondaryFilechoose.getSelectedFile();
                    filenameFieldSecondary.setText(fileSecondary.getPath());
                    //System.out.println(fileSecondary.getPath());
                    //System.out.println("main on secondary browse "+mainInkID);
                }
        }
    });
    btnBrowseSecondary.setBounds(987, 736, 90, 30);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnBrowseSecondary);

    JButton btnOpenSecondary = new JButton("Open");
    btnOpenSecondary.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {               
            System.out.println("main before secondary open " + mainInkID);
            System.out.println("secondary before secondary open " + secondaryInkID);

            secondaryInkID = SQLhandler.getIDs(fileSecondary);
            secondaryInkName = SQLhandler.getNames(fileSecondary);
            secondaryInkColor = SQLhandler.getColors(fileSecondary);

            System.out.println("main open ID" +mainInkID);
            //System.out.println("main open Color" +mainInkColor);
            //System.out.println("main open Name" +mainInkName);

            System.out.println("secondary open ID" +secondaryInkID);
            //System.out.println("secondary open Color" +secondaryInkColor);
            //System.out.println("secondary open Name" +secondaryInkName);

            drawSecondary();

        }
    });
    btnOpenSecondary.setBounds(1084, 736, 90, 30);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnOpenSecondary);

    JButton btnBrowseMain = new JButton("Browse");
    btnBrowseMain.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
             JFileChooser mainFilechoose=new JFileChooser();
                int retval=mainFilechoose.showOpenDialog(btnBrowseMain);
                if (retval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    //... The user selected a file, get it, use it.
                    fileMain = mainFilechoose.getSelectedFile();
                    filenameFieldMain.setText(fileMain.getPath());
                    //System.out.println(fileMain.getPath());
                }
        }
    });
    btnBrowseMain.setBounds(399, 736, 90, 30);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnBrowseMain);

    JButton btnOpenMain = new JButton("Open");
    btnOpenMain.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

            System.out.println("secondary before main open " + secondaryInkID);
            System.out.println("main before main open " + mainInkID);

            mainInkID = SQLhandler.getIDs(fileMain);
            mainInkName = SQLhandler.getNames(fileMain);
            mainInkColor = SQLhandler.getColors(fileMain);

            System.out.println("main open ID" +mainInkID);
            //System.out.println("main open Color" +mainInkColor);
            //System.out.println("main open Name" +mainInkName);

            System.out.println("secondary open ID" +secondaryInkID);
            //System.out.println("secondary open Color" +secondaryInkColor);
            //System.out.println("secondary open Name" +secondaryInkName);


            drawMain();

        }
    });
    btnOpenMain.setBounds(496, 736, 90, 30);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnOpenMain);            

    JButton btnMerge = new JButton("Merge");
    btnMerge.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("merge");
            for (int i = 0; i < secondaryInkID.size(); i++)
            {
                boolean matched = false;
                System.out.println("secondary "+i+"\t"+secondaryInkID.get(i) );
                for(int x = 0; x < mainInkID.size(); x++)
                {
                    System.out.println("main "+x+"\t"+mainInkID.get(x));
                    if (secondaryInkID.get(i).toString() == mainInkID.get(x).toString())
                    {
                        matched = true;
                        System.out.println("matched");
                    }
                }
                if (matched == false)
                {
                    System.out.println("add");
                    //mainInkID.add(secondaryInkID.get(i));
                }

            }
        }
    });
    btnMerge.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    btnMerge.setBounds(416, 807, 359, 44);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnMerge);
}

public void drawMain() {
    String rowData[] = new String[3];
    mainModel.setRowCount(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < mainInkID.size(); i++)
    {
        rowData[0] = mainInkID.get(i);
        rowData[1] = mainInkName.get(i);
        rowData[2] = mainInkColor.get(i);
        //System.out.println(mainInkID.get(i).toString());
        mainModel.addRow(rowData);
    }
}

public void drawSecondary() {
    String rowData[] = new String[3];
    secondaryModel.setRowCount(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < secondaryInkID.size(); i++)
    {
        rowData[0] = secondaryInkID.get(i);
        rowData[1] = secondaryInkName.get(i);
        rowData[2] = secondaryInkColor.get(i);
        //System.out.println(mainInkID.get(i).toString());
        secondaryModel.addRow(rowData);
    }
}
}
```

Sqlhandler:

```
package main;

  import java.sql.*;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.io.File;

  public class SQLhandler {

static Connection conn = null;
static ArrayList<String> inkNames = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> inkID = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> inkColor = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void connect(File file) {

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+file.getPath());
        //System.out.println("connection has been established");
    }

    catch(SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void close() {
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                    //System.out.println("connection closed");
                    }
            }
            catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
}

public static void getInks(File file) {
    connect(file);
    String sql = "SELECT Inkid, Name, DisplayColor FROM Inks";
    //System.out.println("get data..");
    //System.out.println("from SQL before clear" + inkID);
    inkID.clear();
    inkNames.clear();
    inkColor.clear();
    //System.out.println("from SQL after clear" + inkID);
    try(Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs   = stmt.executeQuery(sql)){

        //System.out.println("Querying...");

        while(rs.next()) {

            //System.out.println(rs.getString("InkId") + "\t" +
            //                 rs.getString("Name") + "\t" +
            //                 rs.getString("DisplayColor"));
            inkNames.add(rs.getString("Name"));
            inkID.add(rs.getString("InkId"));
            inkColor.add(rs.getString("DisplayColor"));
            //System.out.println(inkNames.toString());
            //System.out.println(inkID.toString());
            //System.out.println(inkColor.toString());
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    //System.out.println("from SQL after getting data" + inkID);

    }
public static ArrayList<String> getIDs(File file){
    getInks(file);
    //System.out.println("SQL side ID: "+inkID);
    close();
    return(inkID);
}

public static ArrayList<String> getNames(File file){
    getInks(file);
    //System.out.println("SQL side Names: "+inkNames);
    close();
    return(inkNames);
}

public static ArrayList<String> getColors(File file)
{
    getInks(file);
    //System.out.println("SQL side Color: "+inkColor);
    close();
    return(inkColor);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show the code for `SQLhandler.getIDs(File f)`?

Comment: I added it to the original. I mitigated my issue by creating a second SQLhandler class with duplicate code but thats sloppy. Whats my issue here?

Answer (score 2):

Your `get*()` methods always return the same `ArrayList<String>` object you created in these lines:

```
static ArrayList<String> inkNames = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> inkID = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> inkColor = new ArrayList<String>();
```

So the variables `mainInk*` and `secondaryInk*` will reference the exact same `ArrayList` object, like you have two remotes for the same TV.

Well, the solution is easy, buy a new TV... or create a new empty list with `new ArrayList<string>();` which you will fill with your values. In fact, you don't need these static `ArrayList` variables `inkNames`, `inkID` and `inkColor` at all.

Comment: How would I function without them then? The SQLhandler needs to store the data somewhere? It comes in 1 piece at a time.

Comment: @MikeBellew You could use non-static methods (and non-static fields) in your `SQLhandler` class and use two instances of the `SQLhandler` class, one for each file. Then you can use the values from the different files separately.